# Go to the next component after 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone I have such a problem:

I want to go after 60 seconds to the next component.

This is the code I wrote down so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Start() {
    return (
        <Link  to="/end">START</Link>
    )
}

export default Start
```

I was able to do Link, but I do not want it to work with a click, I want it automatically after 60 seconds it will move to the next component

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `history` object.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const SomePage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;
    if(timeToRedirect) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        history.push("/another-page")
      }, 60000);
    }

    return () => {
      if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
    }
  }, [history, timeToRedirect])
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a question, the variable `timeToRedirect`, to what value should it be initialized?

Comment: Depends on your application design, it can be a boolean state.

Answer (score -2):

Try using inside JS Function

```
setTimeout(redirect, 60);
```